# Neo4j rest server v/s embedded

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

In which mode neo4j database should be used embedded or rest server?

My main concerns are :

1. Performance
2. Horizontal scaling (HA,Clustering) - essential as application is very big.
3. Transactional support(in frameworks like SDN,Grails Plugin,structr etc.)
4. Deployment server support like amazon,GrapheneDB etc.
5. Easiness of switching from one to another
6. Scaling(size of database)

Answer (score 1):

Disclaimer: I'm one of the founders of [GrapheneDB](http://www.graphenedb.com).

I'm not an expert in embedded mode so my answer might be biased but I will try my best:

- Embedded is more performant at this time than server
- Clustering is supported in embedded as well as in server
- Transactional support is available in both modes AFAIK. Spring Data, however has currently bad performance over Rest/server.

From my POV embedded has the disadvantage of being coupled to your app/server deployment.

There is one more option which you haven't brought up, which is using [unmanaged server extensions](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/server-unmanaged-extensions.html).

Using extensions you can get the best of both modes:

- You write your code on top of the Java API and it's executed locally, so you get extremely good performance.
- You can run the server in server mode, making operations easier and also enabling you to host on a separate remote host, on any cloud environment.

GrapheneDB supports unmanaged extensions and it's the option we currently recommend for scenarios where extra performance is needed.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.I am not getting the unmanaged server extensions,i think we don't any neo4j server in embedded mode,do we need separate neo4j server in unmanaged server extension mode? which type of code we have to write because to query database i am using SDN(spring-data-neo4j) and what do mean by locally,does this code run on app server or database server itself.Also there is some warning as i think it is difficult to write code in unmanaged server extensions.

Comment: Does GrapheneDB support embedded mode??

Comment: A server extension is a small java function that is given access to the embedded Neo4j database that the server runs on an so can very efficiently access the graph functionality w/o a network layer in between. Yes GrapheneDB supports those extensions.